# Forecast until y = 0 using linear regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, forecast

I am stuck with a problem which might be rather simple.

I have a data frame containing Dates at different intervals (as 4 digit year) and the corresponding values of areas. I would like to perform a linear regression forecast to find out at which year the area is exactly 0 or in other words crosses the x-axis

Example Dataset:

```
Date Area
1934 0.50
1963 0.35
1983 0.28
2004 0.13
2018 0.08
```

Comment: If you're fitting a simple linear regression then that has the form y = mx+b.  Set y to 0 and then solve for x.  It's a simple function of m and b.  If you need a confidence interval around this then that's a slightly different story - but a point estimate is pretty easy to obtain.

Comment: Wow. Sometimes one does not get the simplest thing. I solved the equation. But yes, unfortunately I need a confidence interval.

Comment: You might be able to get this value by putting the solved value of X back into the regression with a Y value of zero - the fitted coefficients should be the same for both regressions, which you can easily verify.

Comment: The fitted coefficients are not exactly the same, they have slight variations after the delimiter.

Comment: Are the results sufficient to give the desired confidence interval to a reasonable degree of accuracy?

Answer (score -1):

Does it satisfy you?

```
df = data.frame(Date=c(1934, 1963, 1983, 2004, 2018), Area=c(0.5, 0.35, 0.28, 0.13, 0.08))

regression <- lm(Date~Area, data=df)

predict(regression, data.frame(Area=0))
```

And the result is:

```
2032.766
```